# Difference between "acute", "chronic" and "obtuse" in the sense of illness

Tags: meaning, differences

I've checked [Oxford Advanced Learners](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/) for *acute*:

> an acute illness is one that has quickly become severe and dangerous
> Compare:CHRONIC

And for *chronic*:

> lasting for a long time
> Compare:ACUTE

Can a disease be both "acute" and "chronic" simultaneously? For example it could be the case where a certain illness quickly becomes serious **and** have long term consequences
Are there any "obtuse illnesses" ?

Comment: I just realized why you mentioned "obtuse"...Obtuse is the "opposite" of acute in geometry, but not medicine.

Comment: -1 The definitions you've quoted indicate the difference. *Acute* "quickly become[s] severe and dangerous" e.g. requiring hospitalisation, but when dealt with properly, then comes to an end. *Chronic* "last[s] for a long time", probably for the rest of one's lifetime, but may come on slowly and is not *permanently* "severe and dangerous" - but there may be *acute episodes* from time to time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**A *chronic* condition is one that persists for a long time.**  Asthma is a chronic condition: if you have asthma today, then you almost certainly had asthma yesterday and will still have it next week.  Source and more details: [Medline](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medlineplus/acute), [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/32570).

***Acute*** has two relevant meanings.  In colloquial usage, it just means *severe*; so in that sense, a condition can be both acute and chronic.  However, **in medical language, it is specifically used in contrast to *chronic;*** an acute condition, in this sense, is something which by its nature is (expected to be) of limited duration; something which develops over a short timescale.  So **in this technical sense, a condition cannot be both acute and chronic.** An asthma attack is *acute* in this sense: it’s a temporary flare-up of the underlying chronic condition.  Source and more details: [Medline](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medlineplus/chronic), [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/2031).

***Obtuse*** is essentially irrelevant to these medical usages; it was used in a comparable sense in the past, but this usage is now extremely rare ([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130058); [Google ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=obtuse+pain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)).   In mathematics, however, it is still used in contrast to *acute*.  An *acute* angle is one measuring less than 90°, while an angle more than 90° (but less than 180°) is *obtuse*.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you cited sources for your definitions. And the word [*obtuse*](http://www.medilexicon.com/medicaldictionary.php?t=62077) does have a medical usage, meaning "dull, not acute," such as an [*obtuse pain*](http://www.md-tips.com/pains/198)

Comment: @JLG: Fair point; will add sources for the definitions.  The corresponding use of *obtuse*, though, is I think obsolete or almost so: the OED marks it as such, and the [Google ngrams graph for *obtuse pain*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=obtuse+pain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) seems to corroborate this.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe try to use sources that don't require a subscription (like the link to the OED). It will not help users who do not have a subscription.

Comment: @JLG: I realise that; that’s why I linked other sources as well.  It is a shame that the OED is paywalled, but for many things it’s the most authoritative and detailed online source I know, so I usually try to include both it and something more accessible.

Answer (score 4):

From:

http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/imagepages/18126.htm

> Acute conditions are severe and sudden in onset. This could describe
>   anything from a broken bone to an asthma attack. A chronic condition,
>   by contrast is a long-developing syndrome, such as osteoporosis or
>   asthma. Note that osteoporosis, a chronic condition, may cause a
>   broken bone, an acute condition. An acute asthma attack occurs in the
>   midst of the chronic disease of asthma. Acute conditions, such as a
>   first asthma attack, may lead to a chronic syndrome if untreated.

Obtuse is a geometry term.  Being called *obtuse* is generally considered an insult.

Comment: So "acute" may cause "chronic" and vice versa? But I think "chronic " causes "acute" doesn't make sense; since the attack should be accounted as a result of "chronic" otherwise what is the point in coining this term as a disease property ?

Comment: @Zeta The quotation comes from a medical website. What qualifications do you have to say that their description & classification "doesn't make sense"?

Comment: @Zeta To explain further, as mikeY says, if you've got osteoporosis, that is an underlying *chronic* condition; because of it you may get a broken bone, which is a short term *acute* condition. The broken bone will heal, but the underlying *chronic* condition continues. Likewise, you may have an underlying disease of asthma - a *chronic* condition; as part of that, you may, from time to time, get individual serious *acute* asthma attacks, needing hospital treatment. Again, the individual *acute* attacks will pass, but you still have the underlying *chronic* condition.

Answer (score 3):

The link, you cited, mentions that in case of illnesses, [acute](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/acute) and [chronic](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/chronic) are antonyms.

The adjective [Obtuse](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/obtuse), which means *slow or unwilling to understand something*, is not used with illnesses.

P.S.- [Acute angle](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/acute-angle) and [Obtuse angle](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/obtuse-angle) are nouns, which are used in geometry.

Comment: Actually I looked up the definitions from the 6th version

Comment: @Zeta "6th version" of what?

Comment: @TrevorD What could it be? Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary. Did you even read the post?

Comment: @Zeta As will be apparent from my other comments (which you appear to have ignored), I did read the post and your quoted definitions - and understood them, and have attempted to explain them to you.

Answer (score 2):

A chronic disease can have an acute onset or acute symptoms, but the disease itself would not be considered acute.

There is no such thing as an "obtuse illness"