# Difference between acute and chronic alcohol?

Tags: differences

I'm analysing a journal article and it mentions the terms "chronic" and "acute" which has confused me.

I tried looking at chronic and acute illnesses both on stack exchange and google with some luck. (I get that acute is limited whereas chronic is long term) Looking at at the post : [Difference between "acute", "chronic" and "obtuse" in the sense of illness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126080/difference-between-acute-chronic-and-obtuse-in-the-sense-of-illness)

My question is, in terms of alcohol, does acute mean limited consumption as in controlled consumptions (like each day), or consuming alcohol for a period of time and never taking it again?

Chronic, by what I understand, is when you consume alcohol for a long term, I assume, in an unhealthy manner?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Alcohol or the consumption of alcohol are not diseases and the terms do not apply to them. *Alcoholism* can be either chronic or [acute](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/acute%20alcoholism).

Comment: "Chronic" and "acute" are not terms in English that are usually associated with alcohol directly, but rather are used either in terms of consumption practices, as @Glorfidel discusses, or the effects of consumption. There is one set of symptoms caused by consumption of large quantities of alcohol over a relatively short time. This set of symptoms is characterized as "acute". There is a different set of symptoms resulting from the ingestion of smaller quantities over a longer time. This set of symptoms is characterized as "chronic". Some sets of symptoms may occur in both sets.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the terms *acute* and *chronic* normally refer to symptoms and diseases. However, the terms "chronic alcohol abuse" and "chronic drug abuse" are often used. Note that some lay-people think that *acute* and *chronic* both mean *severe*, but this is incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "acute", "chronic" and "obtuse" in the sense of illness](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126080/difference-between-acute-chronic-and-obtuse-in-the-sense-of-illness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Acute alcohol *poisoning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_intoxication#Acute_alcohol_poisoning) is caused by drinking large amounts of alcohol in a short time ('binge drinking'), which is more typical to happen to young people at a party. It leads to vomiting and blackouts.

Chronic *consumption* of alcohol, more typical for older people, leads to other kind of diseases, e.g. [alcholic liver disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcoholic_liver_disease).

In both cases, *chronic* and *acute* don't modify *alcohol* directly, like they do with illnesses.